# Run Tomcat Service as Different User on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, user

I have installed Tomcat6 using the 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer download version.  In the setup instructions, it is recommended that "For optimal security, the service should be run as a separate user, with reduced permissions".  I created a new local/standard user (Tomcat) to run the service.  The Tomcat service is listed in my list of Services and it's running under my user profile.  However, I can't figure out how to set/change which user to start it as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply right click on `Computer` and click `Manage`.

Expand `Services and Applications` and double click on `Tomcat` (or whatever the service is called`.

From here, click the `Log On` tab, and click the `Browse` button, follows by the `Advanced...` button, then the `Find Now` button.

Select the user and close all back to the screen where you can type the password for the account. Type the password and click OK.

You may want to start/stop the service to test it works - if there are any problems, you can either check the event log, or it will probably give you instant feedback about the issue.

[image]

Comment: if anyone run into the problem of service not being started after changing user. Open Event Viewer and locate your error message, you might see "user require rights 'Log on as a service'". If so, run secpol.msc, go to Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service, add your user to the list and restart you tomcat service. https://saadsurya.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/run-tomcat7-service-with-different-account-than-local-system-account/

Answer (score 0):

To reconfigure using the command line:
[sc config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308319/510583)

```
sc.exe config "[servicename]" obj= "[.\username]" password= "[password]"
```

Mind the space after the equal sign.

Comment: In Windows 10, I found that the space didn't matter but the square brackets led to errors. I successfully used `sc config MyServiceName obj=".\MyUsername" password="MyPassword"`